# React Native: Modification in third party package and its pods(present inside the ios folder of project) of Project

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am using [`react-native-photo-editor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-photo-editor) for my project but I have added the module itself (I have added the another UICollectionViewCell.xib and UICollectionViewCell.swift files) and on the native actions i want to execute the react-native functions. My question is : how can I make this modification persistant after runnning `pod install` again etc...

I have also added the native module exporting the methods, so i can use them in react-native side, but having issue of native module is not found in the UICollectionViewCell.swift file for direct access.